# Getting the wells names and types in the Petrel platform

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I am using the petrel platform to develop a ocean plug-in. My plug-in it is working properly but now I need to get the wells names and their types (producer or injector) within the simulated case that the Petrel project has. Could someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `IBoreholeSettingsFactory` service interface, which you can discover via `CoreSystem.GetService`. Given a `Borehole` domain object you can get the `IBoreholeSettings`.

This service interface lets you get or set the well symbol via the `WellSymbolDescription`.

The name is available directly via `Borehole.Name`.